# Custom Pagination with Sort, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, pagination

I have a rails 3 app that displays user submissions in order of how many votes they have. I have a model method called "rank" that calculates the score for each submission.  Currently, when listing all the submissions I am using the following in my submissions_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @submissions = Submission.all.sort_by(&:rank).reverse
  end
```

However, I want to add pagination to this, and it seems that neither 'will_paginate' or 'kamninari' will work properly here. This is because I need to sort the database columns by rank before paginating. Is there a better way to phrase my query so that pagination could be created with one of these gems, or do you know of a good custom pagination solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work for you. Using will_paginate, I tried the following and it seems to return the expected results: `@submissions = Submission.all.sort_by(&:rank).reverse.paginate(:page => 1)`.

Comment: i get NoMethodError: undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x103212330>

Comment: No, this is with `will_paginate`. Not sure how Kaminari works, but I think you can just stick the pagination stuff after `reverse`.

Comment: you get this `NoMethodError` when you use `will_paginate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ended up working:

```
@submissions = Submission.all.sort_by(&:rank).reverse
@submissions = Kaminari.paginate_array(@submissions).page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

Comment: In retrospect this should be something like: `@submissions = Submission.order('rank asc').page(params[:page]).per(25)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could calculate rank in SQL? Or, add a column and save it with the record (e.g. before_save :calculate_rank).